# Excel Macro single column transpose to two columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have created the following macro

I have data going all the way to row 3710 in the master data sheet - and I do not know how to force this macro to loop and include all the data

```
Sub Macro3()
'
' Macro3 Macro
'

'
    Range("A1:A2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("A1:B1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("A3:A4").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("A2:B2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: So you want to take the values in Sheet1 A1:A3710 and put every other value in column A of sheet2 and every other value in column B of sheet 2?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a `for` loop. Also Copy/Paste is something we generally shy away from in VBA as well as `.SELECT` and `.ACtivate`. Those are functions that a human performs, but the computer can just set cells equal to other cell's values like:

```
 Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1,1).value
```

Which says Cell "A1" in Sheet1 should be set to whatever the value is in Sheet2 Cell "A1".

Changing things around, implementing a loop to perform your transpose, and using some quick linear regression formula to determine which row to write to we get:

```
Sub wierdTranspose()
    'Loop from row 1 to row 3710, but every other row
    For i = 1 to 3710 Step 2    
        'Now we select from row i and row i + 1  (A1 and A2, then A3 and A4, etc)
        'And we put that value in the row of sheet2 that corresponds to (.5*i)+.5
        '   So if we are picking up from Rows 7 and 8, "i" will be 7 and (.5*i)+.5 will be row 4 that we paste to
        '   Then the next iteration will be row 9 and 10, so "i" will be 9 and (.5*i)+.5 will be row 5 that we paste to 
        '   and on and on until we hit 3709 and 3710...
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells((.5*i)+.5, 1).value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).value
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells((.5*i)+.5, 2).value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i+1, 1).value
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Bulk data is best transferred via VBA arrays, with no copy/paste required.

Something like this:

```
Sub SplitColumn()
    Dim A As Variant, B As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

    Set ws1 = Sheets(1)
    Set ws2 = Sheets(2)

    With ws1
        A = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(3710, 1))
    End With

    ReDim B(1 To 1855, 1 To 2)
    For i = 1 To 1855
        B(i, 1) = A(2 * i - 1, 1)
        B(i, 2) = A(2 * i, 1)
    Next i

    With ws2
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1855, 2)).Value = B
    End With

End Sub
```